# ElasticSearch Java API Search Error

Tags: java, elasticsearch

The each `searchRequest.toString()` and each error info.

I think if you see the summary at bottom before check those search body and error,  should be more easy to understand my problem.

**SEARCH BODY**

```
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 12,
"query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "must" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "2474" : [ "20", "17" ]
                    }
                },
                "should" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "productName" : {
                            "value" : "xxx",
                            "boost" : 3.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "filters" : [ {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "availableStock" : [ 0 ]
                }
            },
            "boost" : -10.0
        } ]
    }
},
"filter" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
                "ecPrice" : -1
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
} ],
"facets" : {
    "productBrandName" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "productBrandName",
            "size" : 10
        }
    }
},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : [ "<font style='color:red'>" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "</font>" ],
    "fields" : {
        "productName" : { },
        "drugTreatment" : { }
    }
}
```

}

**ERROR:**

```
 QueryParsingException[[hy_index] [bool] query does not support [must]];
```

---

**SEARCH BODY**

```
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 12,
"query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "2474" : [ "20", "17" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "filters" : [ ]
    }
},
"filter" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
                "ecPrice" : -1
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
} ],
"facets" : {
    "productBrandName" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "productBrandName",
            "size" : 10
        }
    }
},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : [ "<font style='color:red'>" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "</font>" ],
    "fields" : {
        "productName" : { },
        "drugTreatment" : { }
    }
}
```

}

**ERROR**

```
QueryParsingException[[hy_index] [bool] query does not support [should]]
```

---

**SEARCH BODY**

```
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 12,
"query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : [ {
                    "term" : {
                        "productName" : {
                            "value" : "xxx",
                            "boost" : 3.0
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    "term" : {
                        "2474" : [ "20", "17" ]
                    }
                } ]
            }
        },
        "filters" : [ {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "availableStock" : [ 0 ]
                }
            },
            "boost" : -10.0
        } ]
    }
},
"filter" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
                "ecPrice" : -1
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
} ],
"facets" : {
    "productBrandName" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "productBrandName",
            "size" : 10
        }
    }
},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : [ "<font style='color:red'>" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "</font>" ],
    "fields" : {
        "productName" : { },
        "drugTreatment" : { }
    }
}
```

}

**ERROR**

```
QueryParsingException[[hy_index] [_na] query malformed, must start with start_object];
```

---

**SEARCH BODY**

```
{
"from" : 0,
"size" : 12,
"query" : {
    "custom_filters_score" : {
        "query" : {
            "bool" : {
                "should" : {
                    "term" : {
                        "productName" : {
                            "value" : "撒",
                            "boost" : 3.0
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "filters" : [ {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : {
                    "availableStock" : [ 0 ]
                }
            },
            "boost" : -10.0
        } ]
    }
},
"filter" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must_not" : {
            "term" : {
                "ecPrice" : -1
            }
        }
    }
},
"sort" : [ {
    "_score" : {
        "order" : "desc"
    }
} ],
"facets" : {
    "productBrandName" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "productBrandName",
            "size" : 10
        }
    }
},
"highlight" : {
    "pre_tags" : [ "<font style='color:red'>" ],
    "post_tags" : [ "</font>" ],
    "fields" : {
        "productName" : { },
        "drugTreatment" : { }
    }
}
```

}

This one has no error.

Now, Summary.

No matter I use `should` or `must` at `"term" : {"2474" : [ "20", "17" ]}`.

It always get error when I set `"term" : {"2474" : [ "20", "17" ]}` in query body.

Once I remove `"term" : {"2474" : [ "20", "17" ]}` from query body, it works fine.

Why?

Comment: +1 for your clear question ..!

Comment: @BlackPOP guess i am stupid, that day i got this error by using `QueryBuilders.termQuery(String name, String...values)`. but after you asid it should be `terms` instead `term`, i just can't find the method `termQuery` with parameters `String name, String...values`, just `String name, String value`...

Comment: You almost found the answer..! It happens...Cheers..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Term query expect only one value.  Terms mean more than one value..  Try lik this

```
 "terms" : {"2474" : [ "20", "17" ]}
```

Change term query to terms.. Refer following url
,http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-common-terms-query.html